# Remove user from group

Tags: linux, users, opensuse, group

I try to remove a user from the group `ftp-users` because I use the user to upload files to my webserver via my Netbeans IDE and it always changes the group of modified or new created files to `ftp-users` and then I loose rights to open these files.

**# groups myuser**

> myuser: ftp-users www

**# gpasswd -d myuser ftp-users**

> Removing user myuser from group ftp-users
>
> gpasswd: user 'myuser' is not a member of 'ftp-users'

If I call groups again, then I get:

**# groups myuser**

> myuser: ftp-users www

---

First I killed the user session with `skill -STOP -u myuser`. But if I execute `groups myuser` then the removed group `ftp-user` is still there. I even rebooted the server.

Comment: maybe it's the primary group for that user?

Comment: `id -g` or `id -gn` to check if it is the primary group for user.

Answer (score 1):

First I switched to the user:

```
su myuser
```

Then I checked the primary group

```
id -gn
```

> ftp-users

So I changed the primary group to **www**:

```
sudo usermod -g www myuser
```

And `exit`ed

Now If I call `groups myuser` I get:

> myuser: www

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
gpasswd -d myuser ftp-users
```

Should do the trick as you've said. But groups can still give the same result even if you removed the user from the group.

Did you logout from myuser and logged in again? This looks like all you need.

Comment: First I killed the user session with `skill -STOP -u myuser`. But if I execute `groups myuser` then the removed group `ftp-user` is still there. I even rebooted the server.

Comment: Please post this files: /etc/group, /etc/passwd.

Log in to your server as root. Make sure there are no other login sessions. Run "groups myuser" and post the output. And then try "gpasswd -d myuser ftp-users" and post the output.